# NOT NULL constraint failed: tasks_task.user_id

Tags: django

I'm working on a Django project using Python3. I have this error come ups when I'm trying to create a new task.

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: tasks_task.user_id
```

The web application works fine, but when I try to create a new task is when the error occurs, I have read all the posts related to the problem, but I have not found the solution.

I tried to update my sqlite3, but it didn't work.

**This is my code**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.db import IntegrityError
from .forms import TaskForm


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

# Create your views here.


def signup(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'signup.html', {
            'form': UserCreationForm
        })
    else:
        if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:
            try:
                user = User.objects.create_user(
                    username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password1'])
                user.save()
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('tasks')

            except IntegrityError:
                return render(request, 'signup.html', {
                    'form': UserCreationForm,
                    'error': 'Username already taken'
                })

        return render(request, 'signup.html', {
            'form': UserCreationForm,
            'error': 'Passwords did not match'
        })


def tasks(request):
    return render(request, 'tasks.html')


def create_task(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'create_task.html', {
            'form': TaskForm,
        })
    else:
        try:
         form = TaskForm(request.POST)
         new_task = form.save(commit=False)
         new_task.User = request.user
         new_task.save()
         return redirect('tasks')
        except ValueError:
         return render(request, 'create_task.html', {
            'form': TaskForm,
            'error': 'Bad data passed in. Try again.'
        })


def signout(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('home')


def signin(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'signin.html', {
            'form': AuthenticationForm
        })
    else:
        user = authenticate(
            request, username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
        if user is None:
            return render(request, 'signin.html', {
                'form': AuthenticationForm,
                'error': 'Username and password did not match'
            })
        else:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('tasks')
```

**Here's my models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.


class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    datecompleted = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    important = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.user)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using the wrong attribute name when setting the user. Note that all Python attributes are case sensitive:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

but

```
new_task.User = request.user
```

Changing it to `new_task.user` should solve the problem.